# The field 'Changed By' Contains the Value __ That is Not in the List of Supported Values

Tags: azure-devops

I am posting this for others - I solved the issue myself.

Issue: In Visual Studio Online (VSO), I changed my Display Name in my profile via the web portal.  When I opened and subsequently when I would try to save existing work items in Visual Studio 2013 (IDE), I would get the message in that appears in the title of this post.

Cause: Visual Studio Team Explorer was using a cached display name that wouldn't resolve to a user account in TFS.

Comment: Add your resolution as the answer, and mark it as such when you can. That way future people with the same problem will be able to find it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Close Visual Studio 2013, relaunch it, and the display names should be fine and saving items should work again.